# I can't start Apache in XAMPP installation

Tags: 16.04, apache2, xampp

[image]
[image: xampp error]

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation and XAMPP installation. 
I got this error the first time I tried to run XAMPP.

Comment: There is something wrong in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf. Please show us its content.

Comment: I edited the post and added a screen-shot of httpd.conf around line 136. Please have a look.

Comment: I maybe wrong but it seems like SSL modules have been configured with a different version of Apache or vise versa..

Comment: What should I do to fix it.

Comment: What goes on if you just remove line 136?

Comment: Did you try to configure OpenSSL installing Apache... etc?

Comment: I removed line 136 and XAMPP started but Ubuntu gave a error saying system program problem detected.

Comment: Maybe this system error is not connected to this issue. Is `http://localhost` accessible by some browser?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think it's all good now. I restarted the system and no more errors.

Comment: yes localhost is accessible

Comment: It is strange. I have had installed XAMPP in my Ubuntu (without configured https, but with mod_ssl enabled) and don't remember issue like this. Maybe you should try to reinstall it.

Is `/opt/lampp/modules/mod_ssl.so` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for test remove (or better comment `#`) the line `136` from  `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` and try to start lampp again.

If after that `http://localhost` is accessible you must cope with the `ssl` module if you want to have `https` access to yours web server in the future.

I'm sure that you will find exactly what you need in [Bitnami Wiki](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_enable_HTTPS_support_with_SSL_certificates) and [Apache Friends Forum](https://www.apachefriends.org/community.html).

Comment: XAMPP is good stack, especially for Windows. I'm not fully sure what are the pros, but in my opinion it makes things more complicated in Linux.